# Split between two character in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my string,

```
  var str=""{\"checkedRows\":\"[{\"SlNo\":\"1\",\"ItemCode\":\"8\",\"ItemDetail\":\"Cassue Nut\",\"Qty\":\"140\",\"Rate\":\"2000\",\"Amount\":280000\"}]\",\"checkedIndex\":\"[0]\"}"";
```

I'm trying to get substring as below

```
[{\"SlNo\":\"1\",\"ItemCode\":\"8\",\"ItemDetail\":\"Cassue Nut\",\"Qty\":\"140\",\"Rate\":\"2000\",\"Amount\":280000\"}]
```

And i'm trying below code to split

```
var newStr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("[") + 1, str.lastIndexOf("]"))
```

but unable to fetch it.

Comment: This is JSON data, you should parse it and fetch the relevant part from the resulting JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly note that you have an extra leading and trailing double quote around your JSON string. Secondly the JSON itself is completely malformed. You need to fix the errors it has (extra/mis-matched double quotes mostly) so it looks like this:

```
'{"checkedRows":[{"SlNo":"1","ItemCode":"8","ItemDetail":"Cassue Nut","Qty":"140","Rate":"2000","Amount":280000}],"checkedIndex":[0]}'
```

Once you've done that you can parse the string to an object, then retrieve the `checkedRows` property and stringify that again, like this:

```js
var str = '{"checkedRows":[{"SlNo":"1","ItemCode":"8","ItemDetail":"Cassue Nut","Qty":"140","Rate":"2000","Amount":280000}],"checkedIndex":[0]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var newStr = JSON.stringify(obj.checkedRows);

console.log(newStr);
```